# Moving Gravity Submit Button To The Right

Tags: css, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

Looking to move my Gravity Forms submit button to the right. I have moved the next button to the right using this CSS:

```
body #gform_wrapper_22 .gform_page_footer input.gform_next_button { float:right; margin-bottom:1rem; }
```

I would assume that I could use this CSS for the submit button but it is not:

```
body #gform_wrapper_22 .gform_footer input[type="submit"] {float:right; margin-bottom:1rem; }
```

I have also tried:

```
body #gform_wrapper_22 .gform_page_footer input.gform_submit_button { float:right; margin-bottom:1rem; }
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Can we see your HTML so we know how it's structured?

Comment: @HunterTurner https://jsfiddle.net/1erqd8y2/#&togetherjs=z0e4VCkCKz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just select it using the class name.

```
.gform_button.gform_image_button {
  float:right;
}
```

Here is an [updated fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/Hunter377/1erqd8y2/2/)